# Angular 2: Add class to component during routing

Tags: angular

I have followed a snippet of code from Todd Motto to automatically change the title of the browser during routing based on config provided in the route data, and it works nicely.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router,
                private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private titleService: Title) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.watchRouterEventsAndUpdateTitle();
    }

    watchRouterEventsAndUpdateTitle(): void {
        this.router.events
            .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
            .map(route => {
                while (route.firstChild) {
                    route = route.firstChild;
                }
                return route;
            })
            .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')
            .mergeMap(route => route.data)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.titleService.setTitle(data['title']);
            });
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do now is capture the current route before it is transitioned away from and access the component of that route and add a class to it (for an animation when routing away from the component).

I have logged the route, the router event, etc., and I don't see any methods or properties that I can hook into to modify the component.

Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    // ... same code from above

    watchRouterEventsAndUpdateTitle(): void {
        this.router.events
            // ... same code from above
            // ...
            // THIS IS WHAT I NEED, or something similar
            .subscribe(component => {
                component.className = 'foo';
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>` where `$event` is instance of current component

Comment: @yurzui, that's a good suggestion. `$event` contains activated component instance. Now how to catch it in a service? Maybe write custom directive applied alongside with `router-outlet` that will inject the service, listen to `(activate)` event and trigger it on the service?

Comment: @Maximus If you want to use it within service then yes, you can do it something like you have described but seems he wants to use it inside `AppComponent`

Comment: Well my code now has the logic from my question in a custom `RouterService` which I invoke from `AppComponent`, so I would also have to create that directive you guys described and hook into that same `RouterService` from the directive to set the class on the component. I think that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get **component instances** from component tree that is constructed when transitioning to the new state **through a router event** - I don't think that's currently possible.

But you can probably use the `$event` emitted by `router-outlet` - it contains activated component instance:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

You can write a custom directive then apply it alongside `router-outlet` that will inject the service, listen to `activate` event and trigger it on the service

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'interceptor',
    host: {
        '(activate)': 'onActivate(component)',
        '(deactivate)': 'onDeactivate(component)'
    }

})
export class Interceptor {
    constructor(private s: MyService) {}

    onActivate(component) {
         this.s.registerComponentActivated(component)
    }

    onDeactivate(component) {
         this.s.registerComponentDeactivated(component)
    }
}
```

And then apply it like that:

```
<router-outlet interceptor></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer my question. I am specifically wondering what (if anything) I can hook into to reach the component during route transition, because I need to modify the component on the route.

Comment: @Lansana,  what component do you want to reach? how is routing relevent to a particular component?... hook to the event inside the component you want to manipulate

Comment: Ideally this would be at a service level, so that every route event is watched within the app (similar to how I set the browser title in only one place). I now want to be able to add a 'viewFadeOut' to each component as a new route is being requested so that I can animate the component out. I have a way to animate them *in* by just having a `app-root router-outlet + * {...}` css in my main css file and that works just fine without having to use the confusing animation system provided by Angular.

Comment: To extend further, notice how I subscribe to the data on the route and set the title based on the `data['title']` value. I want to do something similar, except instead of the `data` I want to get the `component` to modify it.

Comment: _I now want to be able to add a 'viewFadeOut' to each component_ - what each component? The component tree that gets destroyed when navigating to the other route? Or component tree that is being initialized for the new route? `data['value']` has nothing to do with components

Comment: Yes, but `data['title']` comes from the route that I am transitioning to. I want to grab the component from that route instead of the data property. I need the component so I can modify it, if that's even possible.

Comment: Check my question, updated with an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Maybe that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: @Lansana, I understand now. You want to get instances of all components from component tree that is constructed when transitioning to the new state. I don't think that's possible. Just curios why would you need that?

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. Will thumbs up for the assistance, and will try the directive $event approach.

Comment: @Lansana, I've added the suggested approach to my answer. Let me know how it works out for you. I'm interested in the final solution. Thanks